# Wick Order and Radial Ordering in CFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I am not so much familiar with the computations tools of conformal field theory, and I just run into an exercise asking to demonstrate the following formula (related to the bosonic field case):

$$\cal{R}j(z_1)j(z_2)~=~\frac{1}{(z_1-z_2)^2}~+~:j(z_1)j(z_2):$$

with $j$ defined as

$$j(z)~=~\sum_k \alpha_k z^{-k-1}.$$

My question is should I start the calculation form the Wick ordered term and make the two others appear, because starting from the left side, I don't see how could I develop some calculus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we will outline a strategy to prove the sought-for operator identity $(4)$ from the following definitions of what the commutator and the normal order of two mode operators $\alpha_m$ and $\alpha_n$ mean:

$$ [\alpha_m, \alpha_n]~=~ \hbar m~\delta_{m+n}^0, \tag{1}$$
$$\begin{align} :\alpha_m \alpha_n:~=~&\Theta(n-m) \alpha_m \alpha_n \cr~+~& \Theta(m-n) \alpha_n \alpha_m,\end{align}\tag{2} $$

where $\Theta$ denote the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

1. Note that the current $j(z)~=~j_{-}(z) + j_{+}(z)$ is a sum of a creation part $j_{-}(z)$ and an annihilation part $j_{+}(z)$.
2. Recall that the radial order ${\cal R}$ is defined as
   $$\begin{align}{\cal R}(j(z)j(w)) 
   ~=~&\Theta(|z|-|w|) j(z)j(w)\cr
   ~+~& \Theta(|w|-|z|)j(w)j(z).\end{align}\tag{3}$$
3. Rewrite the sought-for operator identity as
   $$\begin{align}\cal{R}(j(z)j(w))~-~&:j(z)j(w):\cr
   ~=~&\frac{\hbar}{(z-w)^2}.\end{align}\tag{4}$$
4. Notice that each of the three terms in eq. $(4)$ are invariant under $z\leftrightarrow w$ symmetry. So we may assume from now on that $|z|<|w|$.
5. Show that
   $$\begin{align}j(w)j(z)~-~&:j(z)j(w):\cr
   ~=~&[j_{+}(w),j_{-}(z)].\end{align}\tag{5}$$
6. Show (under the assumption $|z|<|w|$) that
   $$\begin{align}j(w)j(z)~-~~&R(j(z)j(w))\cr
   ~\stackrel{|z|<|w|}{=}&0.\end{align}\tag{6}$$
7. Subtract eq. (6) from eq. (5):

$$\begin{align}\cal{R}(j(z)j(w))~-~~&:j(z)j(w):\cr
~\stackrel{|z|<|w|}{=}&[j_{+}(w),j_{-}(z)].\end{align}
\tag{7}$$

8. Evaluate rhs. of eq. (7):

$$\begin{align} [j_{+}(w),j_{-}(z)]~=~&\ldots\cr
~=~&\frac{\hbar}{w^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^{n-1}\cr
~=~&\ldots 
~=~  \frac{\hbar}{(z-w)^2}.\end{align} \tag{8} $$
In the last step we will use that the sum is convergent under the assumption $|z|<|w|$. $\Box$

Comment: Thanks a lot Qmechanic, I haven't done all the steps of you are pointing out in detail yet, but I clearly that this is just an extension of the traditional Wick theorem in QFT, for 2-points function:

$T(\phi_{x_1}\phi_{x_2}) = :\phi_{x_1}\phi_{x_2}: + [\phi_{x_1},\phi_{x_2}]$




I am sorry it wasn't obvious for me earlier, now I will redo the calculations in details, trying to familiarize with it better this time. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Yes, the method is similar to, e.g., my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/18085/2451).