# Why/How is this Wick's theorem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem, superalgebra

Let $\phi$ be a scalar field and then I see the following expression (1) for the square of the normal ordered version of $\phi^2(x)$.

\begin{align}
T(:\phi^2(x)::\phi^2(0):) &= 2 \langle 0|T(\phi(x)\phi(0))|0 \rangle^2 \\
&+ 4\langle 0|T(\phi(x)\phi(0))|0 \rangle:\phi(x)\phi(0): \\
&+ :\phi^2(x)\phi^2(0): \tag{1}
\end{align}

It would be great if someone can help derive the above expression - may be from scratch - and without outsourcing to Wick's theorem - and may be help connect as to why the above is related (equal?) to the Wick's theorem?

- Isn't the above also known as OPE (Operator Product Expansion)? If yes, then is there at all any difference between OPE and Wick's theorem? Is there a systematic way to derive such OPEs?
- Can one help extend this to Fermions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Lubos Motl mentions in a comment, for all practical purposes, OP's sought-for eq. (1) is proved via Wick's Theorem.

It is interesting to try to generalize [Wick's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) and to try to minimize the number of assumptions that goes into it. Here we will outline one possible approach.

I) Assume that a family $(\hat{A}_i)_{i\in I}$ of operators $\hat{A}_i\in{\cal A}$ lives in a (super) operator algebra ${\cal A}$

1. with (super) commutator $[\cdot,\cdot]$, and
2. with [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28algebra%29) $Z({\cal A})$.

Here

1. the index $i\in I$ runs over an index set $I$ (it could be continuous), and
2. the index $i$ contains information, such as, e.g., position $x$, time instant $t$, annihilation/creation label, type of field, etc., of the operator $\hat{A}_i$.

II) Assume that
$$
\forall i,j\in I~: \qquad [\hat{A}_i,\hat{A}_j]  ~\in~Z({\cal A}).
$$

III) Assume that there are given two ordering prescriptions, say $T$ and $::$. Here $T$ and $::$ could in principle denote any two ordering prescriptions, e.g. time order, normal order, radial order, Weyl order$^1$, etc. This means that the index set $I$ is endowed with two [strict total orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), say, $<$ and $\prec$, respectively, such that

1. The $T$ symbol is (graded) multilinear wrt. [supernumbers](http://planetmath.org/supernumber).
2. $ T(\hat{A}_{\pi(i_1)}\ldots\hat{A}_{\pi(i_n)})~=~(-1)^{\sigma_{\pi}} T(\hat{A}_{i_1}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_n} )$ is [(graded) symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercommutative_algebra), where $\pi\in S_n$ is a permutation of $n$ elements, and $(-1)^{\sigma_{\pi}}$ is a Koszul sign factor.$^2$
3. $ T(\hat{A}_{i_1}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_n} )~=~\hat{A}_{i_1}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_n}$ if $i_1 > \ldots > i_n$.
4. In the special case where some of the $ i_1 , \ldots , i_n$ are equal$^3$ (wrt. the order <), then one should symmetrize in appropriate (graded) sense over the corresponding subsets. For instance, 
   $$ T(\hat{A}_{i_1}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_n} )~=~\hat{A}_{i_1}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_{k-1}}\frac{\hat{A}_{i_k}\hat{A}_{i_{k+1}}+(-1)^{|\hat{A}{i_k}||\hat{A}{i_{k+1}}|}\hat{A}_{i_{k+1}}\hat{A}_{i_k}}{2}\hat{A}_{i_{k+2}}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_n}$$ if $i_1 > \ldots > i_k=i_{k+1}> \ldots >  i_n$.

[Similar conditions 1-4 should hold for the second ordering $(::,\prec)$.]

IV) It then follows from assumptions I-III that the (generalized) [contractions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/393884/2451) 
$$
\hat{C}_{ij}~=~T(\hat{A}_i\hat{A}_j)~-~:\hat{A}_i\hat{A}_j:~\in~Z({\cal A})
$$
belong to the center $Z({\cal A})$. The contractions are graded symmetric 
$$
\hat{C}_{ij}~=~(-1)^{|\hat{A}_i||\hat{A}_j|} \hat{C}_{ji}.
$$

V) Assume furthermore that the contractions $\hat{C}_{ij}$ do not depend on the operators $\hat{A}_k$, i.e.
$$ \frac{\partial \hat{C}_{ij}}{\partial \hat{A}_k}~=~0 $$
in order to simplify combinatoric arguments below.

VI) It is now a straightforward exercise to establish the corresponding [Wick's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) 
$$ 
T(f(\hat{A})) ~=~ \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j\in I}\hat{C}_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{A}_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{A}_i} \right):f(\hat{A}):,
$$
meaning a rule for how to re-express one ordering prescription $T(f(\hat{A}))$ 
[where $f$ is a sufficiently nice function of the $(\hat{A}_i)_{i\in I}$ family] in terms of the other ordering prescription $::$ and (multiple) contractions $\hat{C}_{ij}$. And vice-versa with the roles of the two orderings $T$ and $::$ interchanged: 
$$ 
:f(\hat{A}): ~=~ \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j\in I}\hat{C}_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{A}_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{A}_i} \right)T(f(\hat{A})).
$$
Such Wick's Theorems can now be applied successively to establish nested Wick's Theorems, such as, e.g.,$^4$
$$  
T(:f(\hat{A})::g(\hat{A}):) ~=~ \left. \exp\left(\sum_{i,j\in I}\hat{C}_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{A}_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{B}_i} \right) :f(\hat{A}) g(\hat{B}): \right|_{\hat{B}=\hat{A}}.
$$
These Wick's Theorems may be extended to a larger class of operators than just the $(\hat{A}_i)_{i\in I}$ family through (graded) multilinearity.

VII) Let us now assume that the operators $\hat{A}_i$ are Bosonic for simplicity.
A particular consequence of a nested Wick's Theorem is the following version

$$T(:\hat{A}^2_i::\hat{A}^2_j:) ~=~ 2\hat{C}_{ij}^2 + 4 \hat{C}_{ij}:\hat{A}_i\hat{A}_j: + :\hat{A}^2_i\hat{A}^2_j:$$

of OP's sought-for eq. (1). Finally, let us mention that Wick's Theorem, radial order, [OPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion), etc., are also discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22784/2451) Phys.SE posts.

--

Footnotes:

$^1$ *Example:* The [Weyl/symmetric ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform) satisfies
$$W(f(\hat{A})) ~=~\left. \exp\left(\sum_{i\in I}\hat{A}_i \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} \right) f(a) \right|_{a=0}. $$
For more details, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/57340/2451).

$^2$ The [Koszul sign convention](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Koszul+sign+convention) produces a minus sign every time two Grassmann-odd objects are permuted. In this answer $|\hat{A}_i|=0,1 \pmod 2$ denotes the Grassmann-parity of $\hat{A}_i$.

$^3$ Being *equal wrt. an order* is in general an equivalence relation, and it is often a weaker condition than being *equal* as elements of $I$.

$^4$ A nested Wick's Theorem (between radial order and normal order) is briefly stated in eq. (2.2.10) on p. 39 in J. Polchinski, *String Theory,* Vol. 1. Beware that radial order is often only implicitly written in CFT texts. By the way, a side-effect/peculiarity of nested ordering symbols are discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162339/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I like this answer just the way it is, as it makes it very clear that Wick's theorem is not a theorem about QFT, but is rather a completely general theorem about algebras obeying a few simple axioms. The standard textbook treatment with fields and VEV's obfuscates what is really just basic algebra.

Comment: 1. Do you have any references where the above steps are carried out in detail and explicitly? 2. In particular, I am not clear about how the ordering operation $T$ is defined for equal times in QFT and whether it corresponds to what is given in point 4 of condition III. 3. Also, I'm having trouble proving Wick's theorem in VI, some extra details would be extremely helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Notes for later: $T(\hat{A}_1 \ldots \hat{A}_n)^{\dagger}= AT(\hat{A}_1^{\dagger} \ldots \hat{A}_n^{\dagger})$.