# Wick's theorem proof details

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, wick-theorem

Let's have [Wick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) in following form:
for fields 
$$
A_{i}(x) ~=~ A_{i}^{+}(x) + A_{i}^{-}(x),
$$
where first summand contains creation operator and the second contains destruction one, is a fair to say
$$ \tag{1}
T(A_{1}...A_{n}) ~=~ \sum_{k}(-1)^{\sigma}\overline{A_{i_{1}}A_{i_{2}}}~\overline{A_{i_{3}}A_{i_{4}}}\ldots \overline{A_{i_{2k - 1}}A_{i_{2k}}}: A_{i_{2k+1}}...A_{i_{n}}:, 
$$
where contractions are denoted with an overline
$$
\overline{A_{i_{1}}(x)A_{i_{2}}(y)} ~=~ \langle | T(A_{i_{1}}(x)A_{i_{2}}(y))|\rangle ~=~ -iD^{c}(x - y),
$$

and normal order is

$$
: A_{i_{k}}(x)A_{i_{k + 1}}(y): ~=~ A^{+}_{i_{k}}(x)A^{+}_{i_{k + 1}}(y) + A^{+}_{i_{k}}(x)A^{-}_{i_{k + 1}}(y) + A^{-}_{i_{k}}(x)A^{-}_{i_{k + 1}}(y) + A^{+}_{i_{k + 1}}(x)A^{-}_{i_{k}}(y).
$$

In the beginning of proof of this theorem one says that permutation of fields in the left and right side of $(1)$ doesn't change it. Why this statement is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP wrote (v1):

> *In the beginning of proof of this theorem one says that permutation of fields in the left and right side of (1) doesn't change it.*

Answer: This is essentially due to the fact that operator ordering prescriptions (such as e.g. time ordering $T$ or normal ordering $::$) are [(graded) symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercommutative_algebra) 
$$ T(\hat{A}_{\pi(i_1)}\ldots\hat{A}_{\pi(i_n)})
~=~\pm T(\hat{A}_{i_1}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_n} ),$$
$$ :\hat{A}_{\pi(i_1)}\ldots\hat{A}_{\pi(i_n)}:
~=~\pm :\hat{A}_{i_1}\ldots\hat{A}_{i_n} :,$$
where $\pi\in S_n$ is a permutation of $n$ elements. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451) Phys.SE answer. So more generally, the statement reads:

> *Permutation of fields in the left and right side of (1) doesn't change it, up to possibly an overall sign on both sides in the case of Grassmann-odd operators.*