# Normal order vs Time order for fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

For a conformal field $X$, Polchinski gives a relation between the time ordering $T$ (or equivalently the radial ordering ${\cal R}$) of a functional of identical fields and the normal ordering, which is
$$
T(\mathscr{F}) ~=~ \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\int d^2z_1d^2z_2 \Delta(z_1,z_2)\frac{\delta}{\delta X(z_1)}\frac{\delta}{\delta X(z_2)}\right) :\mathscr{F}: \tag{2.2.8}
$$

Is there a similar expression for time order products of *different* fields, i.e. a fermion pair $\overline{\psi}(x)\psi(y)$?

Comment: Keep reading. In section 2.5 he introduces $bc$ CFT ($bc$ - anticommuting ghosts). Also, in volume 2 there is superconformal field theory with proper fermions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the generalization to several fields $(\hat{A}_i)_{i\in I}$ is
$$T(f(\hat{A})) ~=~ \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j\in I}\hat{C}_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{A}_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{A}_i} \right):f(\hat{A}):$$ where we have used [DeWitt's condensed notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation). We stress that for Grassmann-odd fields, it is important to pay attention to sign factors. See my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451) for notation & details.