# Clarification of derivation in Tong's lectures on String theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I'm reading Tong's [Lectures on String Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) chapter 4 on conformal field theory. The PDF can be found [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/string.pdf). I'm trying to understand his proof of claim 2 in section 4.3.3, but I can't seem to grasp what happens from the first line to the second line in equation 4.26.

If I start doing the derivation myself, the initial expression is
$$\partial X(z) :e^{ikX(w)} : = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(ik)^n}{n!} \partial X(z) : X(w)^n:\tag{4.26}$$
It is implicit that $\partial = \partial_z$. Furthermore I know that $$\partial (X(z)X(w)) = \partial X(z) X(w) + X(z) \partial X(w) = \partial X(z) X(w)$$ and that $$\partial (X(z)X(w)) = \partial \left( - \frac{\alpha'}{2} \ln (z - w) + \dots   \right) = -\frac{\alpha'}{2} \frac{1}{z - w} + \dots $$
This looks useful but I cannot figure out how to combine them into something useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

1. Tong is in eq. (4.26) calculating the OPE $${\cal R}[\partial X(z) :e^{ikX(w)}:]~=~\ldots\tag{4.26}$$ Note that the radial order ${\cal R}$ is implicitly written in Tong's text.
2. He is using a nested Wick's theorem between radial order ${\cal R}$ and normal order $: :$, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451).
3. The contraction is
   $$ \begin{align}C(z,w)~=~&{\cal R}[ X(z) X(w)]~-~ :X(z) X(w):\cr
   ~=~&-\frac{\alpha^{\prime}}{2}\ln(z-w)\mathbb{1}.\end{align}\tag{4.22}$$
4. The singular terms on the RHS of eq. (4.26) come from all possible single-contractions between $\partial X(z)$ and the vertex operator $:e^{ikX(w)}:$.

Comment: This cleared it up, thank you very much.