How to derive this OPE?
I have problem with deriving $$T(z)X^{\mu}(w,\bar{w})\sim \frac{1}{z-w}\partial X^{\mu}(w,\bar{w}) + \cdots .$$
We know that $$\langle X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w)\rangle =\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\nu\nu}\frac{1}{z-w}.$$ On the other hand, $$T(z)=-2:\partial X(z)\cdot \partial X(z):$$ Then we have: $$T(z)X^{\mu}(w)=   -2:\partial X(z)\cdot \partial X(z): X^{\mu}(w).$$
Now what we can do? I don't know how to use Wick's theorem here. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Why don't you know how to use it here? What is stopping you exactly?

@Prahar I couldn't find the Wick's theorem in BBS book (my question comes from this book) and I can't match Wick's theorem in other books with my question. Could you please help me how to use it to solve my question?

Wick's theorem is one of the most basic things you learn in QFT. If you don't already know it, you are not ready to study string theory.

@Prahar could you please help me in this particular case to learn it?

@Qmechanic Could you please help me about my question? I don't know how to use Wick's theorem in these types of questions. What is the standard Wick's thm in string theory? Is there a reference for it? I can't find it in BBS book. I found it in Srednicki book but I can't match it with my question here. Thank you.

Is this post following a reference? BBS? Which page?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/584018/2451

@Qmechanic I really appreciate your help and nice link. I got it now.

You're welcome. Consider to write an answer to help future readers.

@Qmechanic Consider it done. I'll do it.

Dear @Qmechanic , thank you so much for your help.

For three operators $X,Y,Z$, we have: $$XY=:XY:+\langle XY\rangle$$ and $$XYZ=:XYZ:+X\langle YZ\rangle +Y\langle ZX\rangle +Z\langle XY\rangle .$$ Then we have: $$:XY:Z=(XY-\langle XY\rangle )Z=XYZ-\langle XY\rangle Z$$ $$=:XYZ:+X\langle YZ\rangle +Y\langle XZ\rangle .$$ In particular, $$: \partial X\cdot \partial X:X^{\mu}=:\partial X^{\nu}\partial X_{\nu}:X^{\mu}$$ $$=:\partial X^{\nu}\partial X_{\nu}X^{\mu}:+\partial X^{\nu}\langle \partial X_{\nu}X^{\mu}\rangle +\partial X^{\nu}\langle \partial X_{\nu}X^{\mu}\rangle$$ $$=:\partial X^{\nu}\partial X_{\nu}X^{\mu}:+2\partial X^{\nu}\langle \partial X_{\nu}X^{\mu}\rangle \sim 2\partial X^{\nu}\langle \partial X_{\nu}X^{\mu}\rangle .$$ Therefore, $$T(z)X^{\mu}(w)\sim -4\partial X^{\nu}(z)\langle \partial X_{\nu}(z)X^{\mu}(w)\rangle .$$
