# How one can use Wick's theorem for the product $A:\mathrel{B^{n}}:$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, wick-theorem

I try to use [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) in the case that some products we deal with are already normal ordered.

My guess is that it could be something like
\begin{equation}
A:\mathrel{B^{n}}:~=~:\mathrel{AB^{n}}:+nA^{\bullet}B^{\bullet}:\mathrel{B^{n-1}}:\tag{1}
\end{equation}
I tried to prove that by induction but I failed, maybe the formula is similar and I am somehow close, or maybe my intuition totally fails. How one could approach such a problem?

Also, how would that Wick's expansion look in the general case: $$A_{1}\cdots A_{n}:\mathrel{B_{1}\cdots B_{m}}:~ ?\tag{2}$$

Comment: Which context? Which references? Which pages?

Comment: I don't know if the context is important I try to calculate OPE of the current and vertex operator for the free boson conformal field theory and this is the problem I met by the way. But I think the problem is interesting on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is usually a second implicitly written operator ordering besides the normal order. [This plays a role in e.g. eq. (2).] E.g. in the context of 2D conformal field theory, there is typically an implicitly written radial ordering ${\cal R}$.
2. Then eqs. (1) and (2) become examples of a nested [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) discussed in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451).
3. Eq. (1) is correct, because the only possible terms are a term with no contraction and $n$ terms with a single $AB$ contraction.
4. Eq. (2) becomes a sum of all possible $AA$ and $AB$ (but not $BB$) contractions.

Comment: Yes indeed, I also meant radial order. Could you show how (1) follows from that nested Wick's theorem? I am a little bit lost in its formulation

Comment: I updated the answer.