# Product of normally ordered exponentials as a normal ordering of product of exponentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, quantum-optics, wick-theorem

I want to simplify a product of normally ordered exponentials that are in the following form

$$:e^{x(\hat{a}^\dagger+\alpha_x^*)(\hat{a}+\alpha_x)}:\times   :e^{y(\hat{a}^\dagger+\alpha_y^*)(\hat{a}+\alpha_y)}:$$

where $\times$ is the usual multiplication, $\hat{a}$ is a bosonic annihilation operator, $\alpha_i$ are complex numbers, and $:\bullet:$ represents normal ordering where you rewrite the all $\hat{a}^\dagger$ to the left of $\hat{a}$.

Is the solution to this simply $::$ of the product? It looks to me that it shouldn't. Is there a trick or an identity to solve this, in case it is not trivial?

Comment: Why don't you try out first with two exponentials and then apply the definition to see where it gets you?...

Comment: Thanks, I should check out the product of two terms first.

Answer (score 5):

Comments to the post (v3):

1. OP is right that a product $~:\hat{A}::\hat{B}:~$ of normal-ordered operators is not necessarily the same as normal-ordering $~:\hat{A}\hat{B}:~$  the product of operators. Instead the 2 expressions are related via a pertinent nested Wick theorem/star product, such as e.g.
   $$:\hat{A}\hat{B}:~=~:\hat{A}:\exp\left(-\frac{\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{\partial}}{\partial \hat{a}}\frac{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\partial}}{\partial \hat{a}^{\dagger}}\right):\hat{B}:$$
   similar to my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451).
2. For what it's worth, a single factor in OP's product can be rewritten as
   $$:e^{x(\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\alpha^{\ast})(\hat{a}+\alpha)}:~=~  e^{x(\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\alpha^{\ast})\alpha} :e^{x \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}}:e^{x\alpha^{\ast}\hat{a}} $$

Comment: Is there a way to write $:\hat{A}::\hat{B}: = :\hat{C}:$ instead for some $\hat{C}$? If I have just one normally ordered exponential term in the end, even with some complicated argument, then it would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simpler example, where $f=a a^\dagger a a^\dagger$.

Then
$$
:f: \times :f: = \left(a^\dagger a^\dagger a a\right) \left(a^\dagger a^\dagger a a\right) = a^\dagger a^\dagger a a a^\dagger a^\dagger a a
$$
whereas
$$
:f\times f: = :\left(a a^\dagger a a^\dagger\right) \left(a a^\dagger a a^\dagger\right): = a^\dagger a^\dagger a^\dagger a^\dagger a a a a
$$
Therefore
$$
:f: \times :f: \neq :f\times f:
$$

Comment: Yes! This would mean it's not a simple normal ordering of the exponentials. Is there a way to solve it though using some identity?

Comment: @SaurabhShringarpure Not that I'm aware of, but that doesn't mean that there is no such trick.

Comment: @SaurabhShringarpure I foresee a lot of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff in your future.