# Confusion regarding simplifying normal ordered products in CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I am studying CFT on my own and have some confusion regarding applications of [Wick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) to simplify normal ordered products to time ordered products. Wick's theorem is fairly straightforward, which says that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{T}(\text{string of operators}) = :\sum_\text{contractions} \text{string of operators}:
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{T}(\cdots)$ denotes time ordering and $:\cdots:$ denotes normal ordering. So far so good.

My confusion starts here. For reference, I am using [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) set of notes. Consider the stress energy tensor of the free boson
\begin{equation}
T(z) = -\frac{1}{\alpha'}:\partial X(z)\partial X(z):\tag{4.25}
\end{equation}
To calculate the OPE of this stress energy tensor with the field $\partial X$ we write
\begin{equation}
T(z) \partial X(w) = -\frac{1}{\alpha'}:\partial X(z) \partial X(z):\partial X(w)\tag{p.80}
\end{equation}
The LHS is a time ordered product whereas the RHS is a product of *two* normal ordered products. To rewrite the RHS as a time ordered product, Tong writes that we make us of contractions, i.e. "replace the pair by the propagator"
\begin{equation}
\partial X(z) \partial X(w) = -\frac{\alpha'}{2}\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}+\text{non-singular}.\tag{4.23}
\end{equation}
I don't understand how this follows from Wick's theorem, since the statement of Wick's theorem is a very different one. Can someone please explain, it will be of great help.

Comment: The "string of operators: that you write on the LHS of Wick's theorem is a product of normal-ordered operators. This is the same as in (p.80).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eq. (4.23) is Wick's theorem between the (implicitly written) radial ordering ${\cal R}$ and the normal ordering $::$
$$ {\cal R}[\partial X(z) \partial X(w)] ~=~ \underbrace{-\frac{\alpha^{\prime}}{2}\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}}_{\text{contraction}}~+~  \underbrace{:\partial X(z) \partial X(w):}_{\text{non-singular terms}}\tag{4.23} $$
cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451) Phys.SE post.