# Quick question regarding Wick's theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wick-theorem

Let $T\{...\}$ denote time-ordering, $N\{...\}$ normal-ordering and $\left<ab\right>$ be the propagator.

Wick's theorem states that

$$ T\{ab\} = N\{ab\} + \left<ab\right>. $$

I now apply time-ordering to both sides of this equation. Because $T$ is idempotent, $T\{T\{ab\}\}=T\{ab\}$. Also $T\{N\{ab\}\}=T\{ab\}$ because we re-order operators inside the $T\{...\}$ anyway. $\left<ab\right>$ is not an operator, so time-ordering acts on it trivially. We obtain:

$$ T\{ab\} = T\{ab\} + \left<ab\right>$$

$$ \left<ab\right> = 0.$$

This result is obviously incorrect. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the problem is that the "time-ordering operator" is not really an operator. A look on the [wikipedia article on path-ordering operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering) tells you that it is called a [meta-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-operator), where "A meta-operator is different from an operator in that it does not correspond to a linear transform in the Hilbert space."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I) It is true that operator ordering procedures are idempotent operations

$$\tag{1} T(T(\ldots))~=~T(\ldots)\quad\text{and}\quad N(N(\ldots))~=~N(\ldots). $$

But it is *not* true that the outermost ordering cancels the effect of the innermost ordering

$$\tag{2} T(N(\ldots))~=~T(\ldots)\quad\text{and}\quad N(T(\ldots))~=~N(\ldots). \quad (\longleftarrow \text{Both Wrong!})$$

In fact, the opposite is true

$$\tag{3} T(N(\ldots))~=~N(\ldots)\quad\text{and}\quad N(T(\ldots))~=~T(\ldots),$$

as a special case of a nested${}^1$ Wick's Theorem, cf. Section II below.

*Example.* If for two operators $a$ and $b$, we have the relation

$$\tag{4} T(ab) ~=~ N(ab) + \langle ab\rangle {\bf 1},$$

where the contraction $\langle ab\rangle$ is a $c$-number, then

$$T(N(ab))~\stackrel{(4)}{=}~T\left(T(ab)- \langle ab\rangle {\bf 1}\right)
~\stackrel{\text{linearity}}{=}~T(T(ab))- T\left(\langle ab\rangle {\bf 1})\right)$$
$$\tag{5} ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~T(ab)- \langle ab\rangle {\bf 1}
~\stackrel{(4)}{=}~N(ab)~\neq~ T(ab) .$$

II) More generally, if we want to bring a nested expression of the form

$$ \tag{6} T\left(N(\ldots) \ldots N(\ldots)\right) $$

on normal ordered form, there is a nested${}^1$ Wick's Theorem, which states that we should only include contractions between pairs of operators who belong to *different* normal order symbols.

*Example.* In OP's case (5), this means for the lhs. that

$$ \tag{7} T(N(ab))~=~N(ab), $$

since $a$ and $b$ belong to the *same* normal order symbol $N(ab)$, while the rhs. is

$$\tag{8} T(ab) ~=~ N(ab) + \langle ab\rangle {\bf 1}.$$

[Note that $N(a)=a$ and $N(b)=b$.] See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451) Phys.SE posts.

--

${}^1$
A nested Wick's Theorem (between radial order and normal order) is briefly stated on p. 39 in J. Polchinski, *String Theory,* Vol. 1. Beware that radial order is often only implicitly written in CFT texts.