# Time-ordered product of two normal-ordered products of fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, wick-theorem

Suppose you have a scalar field theory with field operators $\phi(x)=\phi(x)_+ + \phi(x)_- $ that can be decomposed into terms of annihilation and destruction operators.
Let 
$$
D(x-y) = <0|T(\phi(x)\phi(y))|0>
$$ be the propagator for said theory.
I am trying to prove the relation
$$
<0|T(:\phi(x)^n::\phi(y)^m:)|0> = n!\: D(x-y)^n \delta_{n,m}.
$$
My fírst attempt at a solution was to plug in the definitions of time ordered and normal ordered products, use the decomposition of $\phi(x)$ and the Multinomial theorem for expressing $\phi(x)^n$ and $\phi(y)^m$.
After this had lead me nowhere I looked up Wicks theorem and tried to use it. But I don't know what the contraction of normal ordered product with a normal ordered product is. I know you can use it for expressions like $$<0|T(:\phi(x)^n\phi(y)^m:)|0>,$$ but  my problem is obviously different from that.
Then I tried to prove the relation by complete induction, which failed because I couldn't express the $(n+1)$ term on the left hand side in terms of the result for the case $n$.
My last resort was to work this out for the case $n=m=2$ and then work my way up to arbitrary powers.
I looked my problem up in Peskin and Schröder's book and also in Schwabel's Advanced Quantum Mechanics, but found nothing than the definitions and the introductory examples.
I closely studied the questions

- [Time-ordering vs normal-ordering and the two-point function/propagator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/)
- [Why/How is this Wick's theorem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183978/
- [Quick question regarding Wick's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162339/)

I've been thinking about this problem for man days now and any help or idea, I can start from, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. The starting point is the 2-point relation
   $$T(\phi(x)\phi(y)) ~-~:\phi(x)\phi(y):
   ~=~ C(x,y)~{\bf 1}, \qquad C(x,y)~\equiv~\langle 0 | T(\phi(x)\phi(y))|0\rangle,\tag{1} $$
   cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. The relevant [Wick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem) is a nested Wick's theorem
   $$ T(:\phi(x)^n::\phi(y)^m:)~=~\exp\left( C(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi(y)}\right): \phi(x)^n \phi(y)^m:$$
   $$~=~\sum_{r=0}^{\min(n,m)} \frac{n! }{(n\!-\!r)!}  \frac{m!}{(m\!-\!r)}\frac{C(x,y)^r}{r!} : \phi(x)^{n-r} \phi(y)^{m-r}:, \tag{2}$$
   cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451). The main point is that when applying the nested Wick's theorem to the lhs. of eq. (2), one should only include all possible contractions between *different* normal order symbols, and exclude contractions that are purely within the *same* normal order symbol.
3. Recall the fact that 
   $$   \langle 0 | :\phi(x_1)\ldots \phi(x_n):|0\rangle ~=~\delta_n^0. \tag{3} $$
4. Combine eqs. (2) and (3) to conclude the sought-for identity 
   $$  \langle 0 |T(:\phi(x)^n::\phi(y)^m:)|0\rangle~=~n!~\delta_n^m ~C(x,y)^n. \tag{4}$$

Comment: thank you very, very much for your clear answer. It helped me a lot.