# Normal Order of Normal Order

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

In the first volume of Polchinski page 39 we can read a compact formula to perform normal-order for bosonic fields
$$
:\cal F:~=~\underbrace{\exp\left\{\frac{α'}{4}∫\mathrm{d}^2z\mathrm{d}^2w\log|z-w|^2\frac{δ}{δφ(z,\bar z)}\frac{δ}{δφ(w,\bar zw)} \right\}}_{:=\mathcal{O}}\cal F, \tag{1}
$$

What I do not understand it is that I would like to have (bearing in mind the definition involving $a$ and $a^†$
$$
::\cal F::~=~:\cal F:\tag{2}
$$
but with this formula
$$
\cal O^2\cal F~≠~\cal O \cal F.\tag{3}
$$

EXAMPLE:

$$
:φ(z)φ(w):~=~φ(z)φ(w)-\frac{α'}{2}\log|z-w|^2\tag{4}
$$
but
$$\begin{align}
::φ(z)φ(w)::~=~&:φ(z)φ(w):-\frac{α'}{2}\log|z-w|^2\cr
~=~&φ(z)φ(w)-α'\log|z-w|^2.\end{align}\tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. *Short explanation:* Polchinski's eq. (1) is *not* a formula that transforms no normal order into normal order: The expression ${\cal F}$ on the right-hand side of eq. (1) is implicitly assumed to be radially ordered. In fact, eq. (1) is a [Wick theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) for changing radial order into normal order, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. *Longer explanation:*   When dealing with non-commutative operators, say $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$, the "function of operators" $f(\hat{X},\hat{P})$ does not make sense unless one specifies an operator ordering prescription  (such as, e.g., radial ordering, time-ordering, Wick/normal ordering, Weyl/symmetric ordering, etc.). A more rigorous way is to introduce a correspondence map  $$\begin{array}{c} \text{Symbols/Functions}\cr\cr 
   \updownarrow\cr\cr\text{Operators}\end{array}\tag{A}$$
   (E.g. the correspondence map from Weyl symbols to operators is explained in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57299/2451) Phys.SE post.)
   To define an operator $\hat{\cal O}$ on operators, one often give the corresponding operator ${\cal O}$ on symbols/functions, i.e.,
   $$ \begin{array}{ccc} \text{Radial-Ordered Symbols/Fcts}&\stackrel{\cal O}{\longrightarrow} & \text{Normal-Ordered Symbols/Fcts} \cr\cr 
   \updownarrow &&\updownarrow\cr\cr
   \text{Radial-Ordered Operators}&\stackrel{\hat{\cal O}}{\longrightarrow} & \text{Normal-Ordered Operators}\end{array}\tag{B}$$
   E.g. Polchinski's differential operator ${\cal O}$ does strictly speaking only make sense if it acts on symbols/functions. The identification (A) of symbols and operators is implicitly implied in Polchinski.
3. Concerning idempotency of normal ordering, see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162339/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Thank you. I read the post about idempotency. But there is still something I cannot understand. The point is that for operator that are quadratic in fields seems to hold but not in general. For instance. If I try to use eq (1) to normal order a constant I woud get $\cal O 1 =1$ instead of $0$ as I should expect.

Comment: @MaPo The normal order of a constant is the constant, why do you expect 0?

Comment: You are right, but i really cannot understand. For instance the example of @ACuriousMind, seems to tell us that it's impossible to really define that operation. I'm very confused and I don't know how to apply the formula.
Still, if the normal order of a constant is the constant isfelf, where is the mistake in deriving eqs (4) and (5) that seems to show that idempotency fails?

Comment: You can only operate with ${\cal O}$ on radially ordered expressions. Therefore you cannot apply ${\cal O}$ twice, since after the first application of ${\cal O}$, the expression is no longer radially ordered.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have understood how to apply properly Polchinski (1). Apart from that what is worrying me now is the example of @ACuriousMind that seems to claim that linearity fails in normal ordering just applying definition, disregarding radial order at all. Is there a way out?

Comment: Linearity $~:{\cal F}_1~ +~{\cal F}_2:~=~:{\cal F}_1:~ +~ :{\cal F}_2:~$ of an operator ordering (e.g. normal ordering) holds if the arguments ${\cal F}_1$ and ${\cal F}_2$ are already ordered in some way, e.g.  radially. (Note  in particular that the pre-ordering of arguments removes the operator ordering ambiguity exploited in the counterexample of ACuriousMind's answer.)

Comment: Shouldn't the arrows under $\cal O$ and $\hat {\cal O}$ go right to left?

Comment: @Hello Goodbye: Thanks! Corrected direction in eq. (B).