# Problem with Wick's theorem (normal ordering of a contraction)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, wick-theorem

Taking the example of two bosonic fields, Wick's theorem is
\begin{equation}
T\{\phi(x_1)\phi^\dagger(x_2)\} = N\{\phi\phi^\dagger\} + N\{(\phi\phi^\dagger)_c\}
\end{equation}
where the subscript $c$ denotes a contraction of the fields. Since $(\phi\phi^\dagger)_c$ is a commutator (more specifically propagator), this reduces to
\begin{equation}
T\{\phi(x_1)\phi^\dagger(x_2)\} = N\{\phi\phi^\dagger\} + (\phi\phi^\dagger)_c.
\end{equation}
My question is that since we know normal ordering of a commutator is zero, why don't we have 
$$T\{\phi(x_1)\phi^\dagger(x_2)\} = N\{\phi\phi^\dagger\}$$ 
only instead of the above? In QED, by expanding the $S$ operator, we also get many terms involving normal ordering of contractions between fields (and other uncontracted fields) but these are not zero. Why? Is the normal ordering of a commutator and contraction different from each other? What am I missing?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323801/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi I have checked that answer but it does not address the normal ordering of a contraction which I see is usually factored out of the $N$ operator. This is what I don't understand.