# Time ordering of Normal ordered products in Wick's theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, wick-theorem

I have a small doubt regarding wick's theorem. 
Is it normal ordered products  are time ordered?
Actually in wick's theorem  we usually  don't write the symbol  of time ordering in front of normal ordered products  that's why I asked,

In S matrix expansion  for a particular process ,
If normal ordered products are not time ordered may  cause occurrence of some process in reverse order, how does this possible?

Answer (score 3):

1. Time-ordering and [normal ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order) are 2 different operator ordering prescriptions.
2. It is not meaningful to apply them simultaneously, because which prescription should we then follow? However nested ordering prescriptions do make sense, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162339/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. (One version of) [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) translates between them. See e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24180/2451).