# Why is Wick contraction a $c$-number?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, operators, many-body, wick-theorem

It is mentioned in Fetter's *Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems* (in *contraction* part of section 8 Wick's Theorem), that:

> contractions are c numbers in the occupation-number Hilbert space, not operators.

(c-numbers are just complex numbers, right?)

I am confused because Fetter defines contractions as *(time ordered operator) - (normal ordered operator)*. How does subtraction of two operator become a number? Is it implied that we surround it with $<\Psi_0|...|\Psi_0>$?

---

Update: See comments for a short answer.

Update 2: See the links in the answer by Qmechanic for a further intuition on defining Wick contractions.

Comment: The difference between the ordering of the operators can only give rise to zero or something proportional to the identity as we're dealing with creation and/or annihilation operators.

Comment: @CountIblis: That's an answer, you should add it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. The main fields assumption that goes into the proof of the [Wick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem) for fields $\hat{\phi}^i\in{\cal A}$ is that their (super)commutators $$[\hat{\phi}^i,\hat{\phi}^j]~\in~ Z({\cal A}) \tag{1}$$ are [central elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28algebra%29) of the operator algebra ${\cal A}$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. For free fields $\hat{\phi}^i\in{\cal A}$, their (super)commutators $$[\hat{\phi}^i,\hat{\phi}^j]~= (c~{\rm number}) \times \hat{\bf 1} \tag{2}$$
   are proportional to the identity operator $\hat{\bf 1}$. Under mild assumptions one may prove that the contractions 
   $$\tag{1} \hat{C}^{ij}~=~T(\hat{\phi}^i\hat{\phi}^j)~-~:\hat{\phi}^i\hat{\phi}^j: ~=~c^{ij}~ \hat{\bf 1} $$
   are $c$-numbers times the identity operator $\hat{\bf 1}$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451) Phys.SE post. Be aware that 
   in the physics literature, the word  *contraction* sometimes refers to the operator $\hat{C}^{ij}$ and sometimes it refers to the $c$-number $c^{ij}$.
3. Eq. (1) does not necessarily hold for interacting fields, and the corresponding contractions and Wick's theorem get modified.