# Wick's theorem and Feynman propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, correlation-functions, propagator, wick-theorem

[image]

(this is the image from book 'No nonsense QFT' by Jakob Schwichtenberg, page no, 426)

The quantity $[\phi_-(x),\phi_+(y)]$ is like an operator inside the bra-kets $\langle 0|$ and $|0\rangle$.
I'm not able to understand the 4th line of this.
How $[\phi_-(x),\phi_+(y)]$ is dragged outside the bra-ket ?? What am I missing here ? Please help.

thanks .

Comment: The commutator is proportional to the identity operator, so you can assimilate it to a complex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the conventions of your book, you have  $\phi_-(x)=\int \! \frac{d^3 k}{(2 \pi)^3 \sqrt{2 \omega_k}} a(\vec{k}) e^{-ikx}$ and $\phi_+(y)= \int \! \frac{d^3k^\prime}{(2 \pi)^3 \sqrt{2 \omega_{k^\prime}}} a^\dagger (\vec{k}^{\, \prime}) e^{ik^\prime y}$. The commutator of these two fields is thus given by $$[\phi_-(x),\phi_+(y)]=\int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3 \sqrt{2 \omega_k}}\frac{d^3 k^\prime}{(2\pi)^3 \sqrt{2 \omega_{k^\prime}}} e^{-ikx}e^{ik^\prime y}\left[ a(\vec{k}), a^\dagger(\vec{k}^{\, \prime})  \right] $$ $$=\int \!\frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3 2 \omega_k} e^{-ik(x-y)} \mathbf{1}=D(x-y) \mathbf{1},$$ where the commutator relation $\left[a(\vec{k}), a^\dagger(\vec{k}^\prime) \right]= (2\pi)^3  \delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}-\vec{k}^\prime) \mathbf{1} $ was used. This shows that the commutator $[\phi_-(x), \phi_+(y)]$ is just a c-number function $D(x-y)$ times the unit operator $\mathbf{1}$ and $\langle 0 | [\phi_-(x), \phi_+(y) ]|0\rangle= \langle 0 |D(x-y) \mathbf{1} |0\rangle = D(x-y) \langle 0 |\mathbf{1} |0 \rangle= D(x-y) \langle 0 | 0 \rangle$, as the c-number function $D(x-y)$ can be pulled out from the vacuum expectation value.