# What is a contraction in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

I have been reading QFT and I am stumbling upon the idea of [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem). The correlation functions have something to do with "contractions". I want to understand what the physical meaning of a contraction is!

Comment: Reading which QFT texts?

Comment: I am following Ashoke Das, Peskin & Schroeder and sometimes Ryder, Srednicki. But my question originates from college lectures.

Answer (score 4):

> I) *Definition.* Given two operator ordering prescriptions, denoted by, say, $T$ and $::$, the corresponding (generalized) **contraction**
>   $$C(\hat{A},\hat{B})~=~ T(\hat{A}\hat{B})~-~:\hat{A}\hat{B}:$$
>   of two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ is the difference in ordering prescriptions.

II) In applications, a contraction $C(\hat{A},\hat{B})~\propto~{\bf 1}$ is typically proportional to the identity operator ${\bf 1}$. Then
$$C(\hat{A},\hat{B})~=~\langle \Omega|C(\hat{A},\hat{B}) |\Omega\rangle ~{\bf 1}.$$
With a slight abuse of language, the corresponding correlator $\langle \Omega|C(\hat{A},\hat{B}) |\Omega\rangle$ is often referred to as the contraction.

III) To see how contractions are important in [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Comment: When drawing Feynman diagrams, we are supposed to connect to points if they appear with contraction right? If that understanding of mine is correct then I am failing to connect these two. Why contraction is represented as connection between two points in the diagram? I hope I could explain my difficulty. I am being unable to figure out why the mathematical terms of contraction result in connection in the diagram?

Comment: Often a contraction has an interpretation as a propagator.

Comment: Yeah, but why is that represented as connection between two points in a Feynman diagram?