# Problem with expansion of normal ordering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, wick-theorem

I am reading normal ordering..and far now I'm able to understand. I am stuck in third line from second expression in the book *Lectures On Quantum Field Theory* By Ashok Das in page no. 237.

It is given that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\,&[\;:\!\phi(x)\phi(y)\!:,\phi^{(-)}(z)]\\
=& [\phi(x)\phi(y) + i G^{(+)}(x-y), \phi^{(-)}(z)] \\
= & [\phi^{(+)}(x),\phi^{(-)}(z)]\phi(y) + \phi(x) [\phi^{(+)}(y),\phi^{(-)}(z)]
\end{aligned}\tag{6.89}
$$

I understand it is derived as 
[image]

I understand that Term highlighted in red commute and zero. Is this correct or am  I doing anything wrong. Does G term commutes with field as I have highlighted in first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the 2nd & 3rd line in eq. (6.89) Ashok Das is using that:

- The contraction $\langle 0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle=-iG^{(+)}(x-y)$ commutes with anything, cf. eq. (6.82). For more details, see my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/18085/2451).
- $\phi  = \phi^{(+)} + \phi^{(-)}$, cf. eq. (6.83).
- The creation parts $\phi^{(-)}(x)$ and $\phi^{(-)}(y)$ commute.

Comment: I have edited my question and added my solution. Is that correct..I am unable to grasp that first term where G and phi commute and zero..and also I have highlighted in red...that is my assumption but don't know why.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for help..is my answer correct which I have attempted?

Comment: It looks OK apart from some curly bracket typos (v6).