# How did Wick's theorem work for Feynman propagator in Dirac Equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, vacuum, propagator, wick-theorem

In David Tong's Quantum Field Theory [Lecture Notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html), Page 115 Eq. 5.34, the Feynman propagator was defined to be

$$
S_F(x-y)=\langle 0|T\psi(x)\bar\psi (y)|0\rangle 
\newcommand{\normord}[1]{:\mathrel{#1}:\;}. \tag{5.34}
$$

However, in Eq. 5.36,

$$\mathrm{contraction}(\psi(x)\bar\psi(y))=T(\psi(x)\bar\psi(y)) \ -\normord{\psi(x)\bar\psi(y)} =S_F(x-y), \tag{5.36}$$

which seemed to indicate that $$\normord{\psi(x)\bar\psi(y)}=0.$$

What happened here? How did Wick's theorem work for Feynman propagator in Dirac Equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the LHS of eq. (5.56) is an operator. This implies that there is an implicitly written identity operator ${\bf 1}$ on the RHS of eq. (5.56). By sandwiching eq. (5.56) with the vacuum state, we only get
$$\langle 0 | :\psi(x)\bar\psi(y):|0\rangle~=0;$$
not OP's last equation.

There is an analogous situation for bosons. For more details, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true $:\psi(x)\bar\psi(y):=0$, but it is true that $\langle0|:\psi(x)\bar\psi(y):|0\rangle=0$.

I just looked up Tong's notes and it looks like he works out a specific example in detail for the bosonic case at eq 3.33 that may be helpful to you.